# Make a stacked bar chart in plotly with alternating segments

Tags: python, plotly

I'm trying to make a stacked bar chart in plotly/python which has 2 categories that are stacked alternatively next to the other. I originally tried using the graph objects function with the mode set to stacked but it always rearranges the bars so all of the same type are grouped together (in my case all of the Resource A sections were side-by-side AABB) but I want them alternating (ABAB).
I managed to make an example close to something I want using timeline in plotly express. It behaves exactly as I want except that I don't want dates along the x-axis, I just want integers which can't be done with the timeline function. Is there a way to do this?

Here is the plotly express timeline examples. Please note this is only an example of how I want the plot to look. **I do not want to use dates** for the x-axis. I want floats with 1 decimal place but I cannot find any other function that produces a similar looking bar chart which does not group the same types together

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28', Resource='A'),
    dict(Task="", Start='2009-02-28', Finish='2009-04-15', Resource='B'),
    dict(Task="", Start='2009-04-15', Finish='2009-05-30', Resource='A'),
    dict(Task="", Start='2009-05-30', Finish='2009-06-15', Resource='B'),

])

fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color = "Resource")
fig.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You did not clarify exactly what integers you want in the x-axis so I will assume it is the amount of days starting from 0. The code below construct two traces, one for each resource. The trick is to use the `base` keyword to put the bars on the right place.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame([
    dict(Task="", Start='2009-01-01', Finish='2009-02-28', Resource='A'),
    dict(Task="", Start='2009-02-28', Finish='2009-04-15', Resource='B'),
    dict(Task="", Start='2009-04-15', Finish='2009-05-30', Resource='A'),
    dict(Task="", Start='2009-05-30', Finish='2009-06-15', Resource='B'),

])

df['Start'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Start'])
df['Finish'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Finish'])
df['Delta'] = df['Finish'] - df['Start']
df['Base'] = df['Delta'].cumsum().shift().fillna(pd.Timedelta(0))

traces = []
for label, df_ in df.groupby('Resource'):
    traces.append(go.Bar(
        y=[0] * df_.shape[0],
        x=df_['Delta'].dt.days,
        width=0.5,
        orientation='h',
        base=df_['Base'].dt.days,
        name=label
    ))

layout = dict(
    barmode='relative',
    yaxis=dict(
        tickvals=[],
        title='Task'
    ),
    xaxis = dict(
        title = 'Days'
    )
)
fig = go.Figure(traces, layout)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, the integers will not be dates. Example is the first bar starting at 0 and ending at 10, next one 10-15, 15-30,30-35.

Comment: Since the length of the bars are proportionate to the duration of the task, those values would not work. If the first bar had a length of 10 the other ones would have a length of 7.931034, 7.758621 and 2.758621.

Comment: OK thanks for your help. I will edit my question as I think it was a bit confusing. I don't actually want the x-axis to have anything to do with dates, the timeline function was just the only thing I could find that came close to the formatting style that I wanted

Comment: Could you elaborate on the logic of how to define the length of the bars? Or is it just something arbitrary?

Comment: It's just arbitrary, the figure is just an example of the way I want the bars to be ordered.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I think the base attribute is what I need. I can achieve something that looks like what I want with this formula x=['A','A']
fig = go.Figure(go.Bar(x=x, y=[1,3.5], base = [0,5], name='M1'))
fig.add_trace(go.Bar(x=x, y=[4,10], base = [1,8.5], name='M2'))

fig.update_layout(barmode='stack')
fig.show()

Answer (score 0):

```
fig = px.timeline(df, x_start="Start", x_end="Finish", y="Task", color="Resource",
                      category_orders={"Resource": ["A", "B"]})
```

#try this